# gitlab 2 month old branch on remote

Tags: git, branch

Today I pulled 2-month-old branch for some work using the following commands

`git fetch origin`

`git checkout -b feature/<branch_name> origin/feature/<branch_name>`

now if I run `git status` I get over 100 files are untracked what is the reason for this ? and now I have to delete this branch I cannot go to another branch to delete this one and the `git stash` is not working either?

what option now do I have without damaging local master?

Comment: If you don't care about any changes that might exist locally, just use `git reset -- hard HEAD`. This will reset your local working tree to the last commit at `HEAD`.

Comment: any damage to local master?

Comment: It won't affect any changes that have been committed and pushed, but any local changes that have ***not*** been committed will be removed, never to be seen again.